# Sorting columns in a text file and deleting unwanted rows in python

Tags: python, list, file

I have a text file with four columns:

```
time serial domain server
```

The content of the file is as follows:

```
15 14 google.com 8.8.8.8
19 45 google.com 8.8.4.4
98 76 google.com 208.67.222.222
20 23 intuit.com 8.8.8.8
45 89 intuit.com 8.8.4.4
43 21 intuit.com 208.67.222.222
78 14 google.com 8.8.8.8
92 76 google.com 8.8.4.4
64 54 google.com 208.67.222.222
91 18 intuit.com 8.8.8.8
93 74 intuit.com 8.8.4.4
65 59 intuit.com 208.67.222.222
```

What I want to end up with is a domain and server combination with the highest serial number as follows:

```
15 14 google.com 8.8.8.8
92 76 google.com 8.8.4.4
98 76 google.com 208.67.222.222
20 23 intuit.com 8.8.8.8
45 89 intuit.com 8.8.4.4
65 59 intuit.com 208.67.222.222
```

Also in,case the serial numbers match, as in the case of google.com for 8.8.8.8, select the row with the least time.

What is the best way of accomplishing this? Reading each line one by one or performing a readlines() to dump everything to a list and then proceeding further? My current code is pretty messy and was looking for other cleaner concise ways of doing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to throw an external library onto the problem, it would be quite easy with `pandas`:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/tmp/test.data', sep=' ', header=None)
new = data.sort_values(1, ascending=False).groupby([2, 3], as_index=False).first().reindex_axis(sorted(data.columns), axis=1)
```

Which will result in:

```
    0   1           2               3
0  98  76  google.com  208.67.222.222
1  92  76  google.com         8.8.4.4
2  15  14  google.com         8.8.8.8
3  65  59  intuit.com  208.67.222.222
4  45  89  intuit.com         8.8.4.4
5  20  23  intuit.com         8.8.8.8
```

You can save this to a file again using:

```
new.to_csv('/tmp/new.dat', sep=' ', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: really slick..I will wait for sometime to see if anyone else has an answer without using an external library, before accepting this as an answer

Comment: @Ianguitar..just to understand what part of the pandas statement ensures that the row with the least time is taken in case the serial is the same ?

Comment: Before the `groupby`, the table is sorted (`sort_values`) according to the serial value. And after grouping, `first` then selects the first matching row of a group, which has preserved the previous ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `itertools.groupby`, after sorting the data appropriately.

```
from itertools import groupby

''' Find domain and server combination with the highest serial number 
    if serial numbers match, select the row with the least time.
'''

print('time serial domain server')

src = '''\
15 14 google.com 8.8.8.8
19 45 google.com 8.8.4.4
98 76 google.com 208.67.222.222
20 23 intuit.com 8.8.8.8
45 89 intuit.com 8.8.4.4
43 21 intuit.com 208.67.222.222
78 14 google.com 8.8.8.8
92 76 google.com 8.8.4.4
64 54 google.com 208.67.222.222
91 18 intuit.com 8.8.8.8
93 74 intuit.com 8.8.4.4
65 59 intuit.com 208.67.222.222
'''

# Read data into a list of tuples, converting time & serial to int
data = [row.split() for row in src.splitlines()]
data = [(int(row[0]), int(row[1]), row[2], row[3]) for row in data]

# Sort and group
data.sort(key=lambda t: (t[2], t[3], -t[1], t[0]))
for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda t: (t[2], t[3])):
    print(list(g)[0])
```

**output**

```
(98, 76, 'google.com', '208.67.222.222')
(92, 76, 'google.com', '8.8.4.4')
(15, 14, 'google.com', '8.8.8.8')
(65, 59, 'intuit.com', '208.67.222.222')
(45, 89, 'intuit.com', '8.8.4.4')
(20, 23, 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8')
```

Once the data has been read into a list of tuples, with the time & serial values converted to integer, we sort on (domain, server, -serial, time). The negative sign means that the serial sorting is done from highest to lowest.

We then group by (domain, server), and take the first item in each group of items that have the same domain & server. This will get us the item with the highest serial number, and if there are multiple items in the group with that serial number the one with the lowest time will be first.

The `groupby` key function could also be written as

```
lambda t: t[2:]
```

---

The code could be made more readable by using proper `def` functions instead of `lambda`s.

```
def sort_key(t):
    time, serial, domain, server = t
    return domain, server, -serial, time

def groupby_key(t):
    time, serial, domain, server = t
    return domain, server

# Sort and group
data.sort(key=sort_key)
for k, g in groupby(data, key=groupby_key):
    print(list(g)[0])
```

---

Conversely, we can make it *less* readable by condensing it into one big incomprehensible nested list comprehension / generator expression. :)

```
from itertools import groupby

src = '''\
15 14 google.com 8.8.8.8
19 45 google.com 8.8.4.4
98 76 google.com 208.67.222.222
20 23 intuit.com 8.8.8.8
45 89 intuit.com 8.8.4.4
43 21 intuit.com 208.67.222.222
78 14 google.com 8.8.8.8
92 76 google.com 8.8.4.4
64 54 google.com 208.67.222.222
91 18 intuit.com 8.8.8.8
93 74 intuit.com 8.8.4.4
65 59 intuit.com 208.67.222.222
'''

newdata = [list(g)[0] for k, g in groupby(
    sorted(((int(row[0]), int(row[1]), row[2], row[3]) 
    for row in (row.split() for row in src.splitlines())),
    key=lambda t: (t[2], t[3], -t[1], t[0])), key=lambda t: t[2:])]

for row in newdata:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without an external library:

```
with open('/tmp/test.data') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(' ')[1]), reverse=True)
processed = []
res = []
for l in lines:
    key = l.split(' ')[2:4]
    if key not in processed:
        res.append(l)
        processed.append(key)
with open('/tmp/new.dat', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(res))
```